# + operator on string and int

Tags: c++, string, gcc

I am using gcc 4.7.2

With the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string x="hello";
    int y=1;
    x=x+y;
    cout<<x;
    return 0;
}
```

I get error:

```
g++     test.cpp   -o test
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:8:6: error: no match for ‘operator+’ in ‘x + y’
test.cpp:8:6: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_algobase.h:68:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/char_traits.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/ios:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/ostream:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/iostream:40,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_iterator.h:335:5: note: template<class _Iterator> std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator> std::operator+(typename std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>::difference_type, const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_iterator.h:335:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cpp:8:6: note:   mismatched types ‘const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>’ and ‘int’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/string:54:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/locale_classes.h:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/ios_base.h:43,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/ios:43,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/ostream:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/iostream:40,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/basic_string.h:2362:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> std::operator+(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/basic_string.h:2362:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cpp:8:6: note:   mismatched types ‘const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>’ and ‘int’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/string:55:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/locale_classes.h:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/ios_base.h:43,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/ios:43,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/ostream:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/iostream:40,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/basic_string.tcc:694:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> std::operator+(const _CharT*, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/basic_string.tcc:694:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cpp:8:6: note:   mismatched types ‘const _CharT*’ and ‘std::basic_string<char>’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/string:55:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/locale_classes.h:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/ios_base.h:43,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/ios:43,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/ostream:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/iostream:40,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/basic_string.tcc:710:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> std::operator+(_CharT, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/basic_string.tcc:710:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cpp:8:6: note:   mismatched types ‘const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>’ and ‘int’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/string:54:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/locale_classes.h:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/ios_base.h:43,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/ios:43,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/ostream:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/iostream:40,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/basic_string.h:2399:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> std::operator+(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const _CharT*)
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/basic_string.h:2399:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cpp:8:6: note:   mismatched types ‘const _CharT*’ and ‘int’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/string:54:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/locale_classes.h:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/ios_base.h:43,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/ios:43,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/ostream:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/iostream:40,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/basic_string.h:2415:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> std::operator+(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, _CharT)
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/basic_string.h:2415:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cpp:8:6: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘_CharT’ (‘char’ and ‘int’)
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_algobase.h:68:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/char_traits.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/ios:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/ostream:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/iostream:40,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_iterator.h:904:5: note: template<class _Iterator, class _Container> __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container> __gnu_cxx::operator+(typename __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::difference_type, const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_iterator.h:904:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cpp:8:6: note:   mismatched types ‘const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>’ and ‘int’
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

Whereas with this :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string x="hello";
    int y=1;
    x+=y;
    cout<<x;
    return 0;
}
```

I get the output:

[image]

Why this strange behaviour in second case?

Comment: Look at the documentation.

Comment: @chris can you explain this? or link to some documentation? I couldn't see anything wrong with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`operator+=` works because it is a non-template method of the template class instantiation `std::string` (`std::string` is a typedef to a template instantiation of `std::basic_string`).  It does something exceedingly unexpected, which is cast that `int` to a `char`, then treat it as a character.

`operator+` doesn't work because the corresponding overload for the free `operator+` is:

```
template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc>
std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>
  std::operator+(
    const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&,
    _CharT
  )
```

which does type deduction on both the `string` type *and* on the scalar `char` type.  Both of these type deductions have equal weight, and there is no consistent type deduction on both!  (For `std::string`, it is a `std::basic_string` with `_CharT`=`char`, while for `int`, it would only match the above signature if `_CharT`=`int`)

In your case, your scalar `char` type is `int`, while your `std::string` is a `std::basic_string< char, /*...*/ >` -- and `char` and `int` do not match!

The particular error in your template spew is here:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/basic_string.h:2415:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> std::operator+(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, _CharT)
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/basic_string.h:2415:5: note:   template argument  deduction/substitution failed:
test.cpp:8:6: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘_CharT’ (‘char’ and ‘int’)
```

We could disable `string += int` by changing `operator+=` into a template function with similar rules.  This might be less surprising.  But it isn't what the standard says.

Comment: Nice. Just one thing, The int type is casted to char, what is it's value? For instance if I modify the expression as x+y+"s"; the output is hellos.

Comment: Its value as a `char` is the same as its value as an `int` if that value fits.  The encoding that `char` is represented in is implementation defined, but often some extension of `ascii`.

Answer (score 1):

Operator + is defined only for string-string concatenation while operator += appends to existing string not only strings, but also char* and char.

The operator+= has an overloaded version which gets char and appends this char to the string.
The int in your case is casted to char and appended to string. That's how you get this strange character at the end of the input.

You should use sstream to append int to a string. Look here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/

Comment: It is not a member but it is overloaded.

Comment: @stardust_ stop using, and more importantly stop linking to, that inaccurate website.  Try [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B), where you'll note that there are quite important differences.

Comment: That's a side effect. My guess is that he wanted to append string "1" to the string "hello". So even if the code works it will not work as he expects it.

Comment: @Yakk. It is not accurate? Wtf? YI knew there is something fisshy because I have seen a couple of times things not adding up. But I had no idea it can be wrong in something this basic. Anyways thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Can't plus string(x="hello") and int(y) types.