# '+' string operator from c++ to php

Tags: php, c++, string

I am porting simple code from C++ to PHP and I got a problem.
I will show two simple test codes that show my issue.

C++ code:

```
string Test = "something";
Test += 16;
cout << Test << endl;
```

PHP code:

```
$Test = "something";
$Test += 16;
echo $Test;
```

Output is diffrent and I don't know how to make '+' string operator from PHP working as in C++ does.
Outputs:

C++:

> something►

PHP:

> 16

Comment: I want the same in PHP, not C++ ;) Sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It already does.
Only: PHP is weakly typed.

Let me explain:

C++

```
string Test = "something";
Test += 16;
```

You have the string Test. Here you add 16 to it.
Because it's already a string, which is a bunch of characters, this 16 will be seen as a character: ►.

PHP

```
$Test = "something";
$Test += 16;
```

You have a variable $Test, which contains a string in the first case.
You add an integer to it. PHP automatically converts the first case to an integer so he can add it. "something" becomes 0, so $test becomes 0 + 16 = 16.

What you want is this, I guess:

```
$Test .= chr(16);
```

For concatenations in PHP, you don't use the plus, but the dot.
For characters, you use [chr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php).

Answer (score 1):

The .= operator in PHP is like the += in C++

```
$Test = "something";
$Test .= 16;
echo $Test; // something16
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you want to have the behavior of the `+=` operator, since the `+` operator won't  work with string and int as arguments, see [+ operator on string and int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15957860/operator-on-string-and-int)

What you want to do is convert the int to a char and then append it to your string, as the c++ `+=` operator does.